# ShowSaveDialog default extension file does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have this code for saving of files on Electron:

```
      const { dialog } = require('electron').remote
      const fs = require('fs')

      var filename = dialog.showSaveDialog({
        title: 'Save object',
        filters: [ { name: 'JSON file', extensions: [ 'json' ] } ]
      }).then(result => {
        filename = result.filePath
        if (filename === undefined) {
        }
        fs.writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(this.fileObj.default), (err) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err
          }
        })
      }).catch(err => {
        throw err
      })
```

But even with above code, it doesn't make the default extension as a json. It is still `All Files (*.*)` so it looks like the `filter` part in my code above does not work.  What am I doing wrong?? Help!

Comment: you have the filters object wrong, it is `extensions` not `ext` `{ name: 'some name', extensions: ['json'] }`

Comment: Same behavior when I use ```extensions``` :(

Comment: Since I can not add pictures or code in the comments see my answer, but I could not reproduce with the most basic code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the most basic electron app and what you have, the below code sets the default value to `json`. You must have something else that is screwing with the value.

```
const { dialog, BrowserWindow, app } = require('electron')

app.on('ready', () => {
  new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })

  dialog.showSaveDialog({
    title: 'Save object',
    filters: [{ name: 'JSON file', extensions: ['json'] }]
  })
})
```

[image: Working Example]

Comment: Hi, I don't think your answer really answers the question, perhaps posting your findings as a comment would be better.

Comment: @Joshua I wanted to make a comment but comments can't have pictures or blocks of code.